# Multiple ModelManager filter methods

Tags: python, django, django-models

```
def by_this(self):
        return super(MyModelManager, self).get_query_set().filter(this=True)

def by_that(self):
        return super(MyModelManager, self).get_query_set().filter(that=True)
```

If i do MyModel.objects.by_this() or by_that() it works.

But i want to do: **MyModel.objects.by_this().by_that()**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others say, you need custom QuerySet. Here are some examples of how to do this:

http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/562/
http://adam.gomaa.us/blog/2009/feb/16/subclassing-django-querysets/index.html

Answer (score 0):

`MyModel.objects` will return your ModelManager type, but `by_this` returns a queryset.  So you can't call `by_that` on the returned object and the chaining doesn't work.  You could do: `MyModel.objects.by_this().filter(that=True)`.  Or just define a `by_this_and_that` method in your ModelManager derived class.

Answer (score 0):

As ars says, your methods return a queryset. So what you need to do is to create a custom subclass of QuerySet, which contains the `by_this` and `by_that` methods, and then in `MyModelManager.get_query_set` return your subclassed queryset.